# ASP MVC Claim Based (ADFS) inactivity problems

Tags: asp.net-mvc, cookies, claims-based-identity, adfs3.0

I use a claim based authentication for my ASP MVC web application. It's working well, but after a while (some minutes of inactivity) I received a blank page with nothing. Worst, I can't access to the authenticate page ...

So I think there is a timeout problem ? If I go to the cookies panel with Chrome and delete the cookie named FedAuth, everything back to the normal and instead of the blank page I can access to my app ...

I check the event viewer for ADFS and IIS and there is no error, everything seems ok. Can someone have an idea ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm wondering, if ADFS cookies it's related to IIS session timeout ? And also I jusck check the ADFS TokenLifeTime, the value is 480 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

After lot of search, it seems that the problem is related to IIS cookie settings, specially the time-out settings (by default 20 minutes).

I change this value and increase it to 60 minutes for my test and in the ADFS side, I put the value none for ExtendedProtectionTokenCheckand. I didn't receive the blank page during the first 60 minutes. But strangely for iOS and MacOS devices, the problem is always there.